# VBA : Connection to mysql, issue on ADODB.Connection

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to connect to Mysql via VBA in access.
I have created my DSN on my computer, the test connection works well.
In VBA I am doing this :

```
Dim S As String
    Set oConnect = New ADODB.Connection
    S = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=localhost ;" & _
        "DATABASE=myDataBase ;" & _
        "USER=root;" & _
        "PASSWORD=root;" & _
        "Option=3"
    oConnect.Open S
```

I am getting this error :

> Defined type by user is not defined.

I have referenced Microsoft Activex Data object 2.8.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `Microsoft AtiveX Data Objects 2.x Library` activated ?

Comment: Change `USER` for `uid` and `PASSWORD` for `pwd`

Comment: Do you have some code around this? Because you only define a string here and the error message can't be on this one as it is a predefined type. +1 for @Hearner comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is :

```
Driver={mysql};  & _
database=nameDB; & _
server=NameServer; & _
uid=NameUser; & _
pwd=PassWord; & _
option=16386;
```

Change `USER` for `uid` and `PASSWORD` for `pwd`

And don't forget to active the library : `Microsoft AtiveX Data Objects 2.x Library`.

Change your `S` to :

```
 S = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};" & _
     "SERVER=localhost ;" & _
     "DATABASE=myDataBase ;" & _
     "uid=root;" & _
         "pwd=root;" & _
         "Option=3;"
oConnect.ConnectionString  S
oConnect.Open
```